# Is it possible to connect the same marketing cloud environment to 2 different orgs?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sandbox

As a marketing cloud admin, in the last few years I worked for some clients having always this configuration:

- UAT sandbox org (Sales Cloud) connected to UAT MID (Marketing Cloud)
- Prod org connected to Prod MID
  having 1 tracking user and 1 API user for each environment.

Is it possible to have 1 MID connected to two orgs at the same time?
Do we have testing and live data in the same environment this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the following setups:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_multi_org_account_and_user_configuration.htm&type=5

Picture one, right hand side:
Connecting one BU to two Orgs: **Not Supported.**

The followup question is probably moot then ("does not apply"), but anyway:

No matter your configuration - unless you have two completely separate Marketing Cloud Instances - you already have testing and live data in the same environment.

Case in Point: All Subscribers List.

Every send to a contact from all BUs will add them to the same list. The "Subscriber Filter"* feature only covers the UI visibility, but still all subscribers from all BUs are physically put into the same All Subscribers list and *all* can be retrieved from at least one BU (namely, the original parent or Enterprise BU), e.g. via SQL or AMPScript Lookups.

Through the ENT. prefix, other BUs can potentially access it as well - this part might be limitable through a Business Rule though, I am not sure.

*https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_define_a_subscriber_filter.htm&type=5

Other Example: All Contacts. Multi Org or not, you have one shared All Contacts List, and one contact count. In your current setup, both test and live contacts count against your contact count.

There is no complete data isolation within a single marketing cloud instance, multi-org or not.

Comment: thanks Jonas, because as you said and as stated in the doc, Multi-org doesn’t support connections for a single business unit to multiple Sales or Service Cloud orgs; how can I get the data from 2 orgs at the same time having only 1 BU (case of corporate license)? Shall I connect the api user to a "testing tracking user" in a sandbox and then reconnect the same api user to a "prod tracking user" in an org prod environment?  thanks

Comment: Well, you're asking the same thing again :)  You cannot do this with MC Connect - you could build your own custom connection from scratch (thats not a recommendation). Also, honest opinion (backed up by a number of arguments): don't connect the sandbox but find other approaches to test your usecases. This will lead down a long rabbit hole though, so I'm not sure the comments are a good place for this :D